# How can I ensure map layer items are always displayed in a QGIS project even when they are turned off?

Tags: qgis

Over the last few years I have been developing a QGIS project for whole farm planning through my job in Agriculture Victoria. The project has about 150 customised layers allowing farmers to easily prepare a highly detailed map of their farm. The large number of layers also makes it easy for farmers to manage what information is displayed at any one time. I am now in the process of upgrading the project to display a number of summary tables (labels) that can be used for Carbon accounting. To do this more easily I have set up a number of layers each containing 3 - 4  rule based items (see below). These items disappear off the layers panel when they are turned off. They can only be recovered by a right mouse click and selecting "Show all items" or by opening up the layer styling panel. This is a bit messy for farmer clients. How can I set to layer items to display all the time?

[image: Screen snip showing nested rule based items in layer panel]

Comment: Which QGIS version are you working with? Can you provide the exact rules and maybe example data? Have you observed this behaviour in other projects or with other layers? Can you provide a screenshot showing what you describe?

Answer (score 4):

This behavior occurs when the option to "filter legend by map content" is enabled. Try disabling it.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Problem solved. Great service!

Comment: As a new user, please be adviced that this side tries to avoid "thank you" messages. Instead, it encourages you to accept the answer and/or upvote it: click the checkmark right to the answer to accept it - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
Just click the checkmark, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235